# how to make tkinter identify a defined object?

Tags: python, tkinter

The code:

```
from tkinter import *

def show (A, B, C, D):

    if A == "Large":
        
        Label1 = Label(root, text=A).pack()

    if B == "Medium":
        
        Label1 = Label(root, text=B).pack()

    if C == "Small":
        
        Label1 = Label(root, text=C).pack()

    if D == "Infinitesimal":
        
        Label1 = Label(root, text=D).pack()

def clear ():
    Label1.destroy()
        

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500+200+200")
  
var1 = StringVar()
var2 = StringVar()
var3 = StringVar()
var4 = StringVar()

a =Checkbutton(root, text="Large?", variable=var1, onvalue="Large")
a.deselect()
a.pack()

b =Checkbutton(root, text="Medium?", variable=var2, onvalue="Medium")
b.deselect()
b.pack()

c =Checkbutton(root, text="Small?", variable=var3, onvalue="Small")
c.deselect()
c.pack()

d =Checkbutton(root, text="Infinitesimal?", variable=var4, onvalue="Infinitesimal")
d.deselect()
d.pack()

W = Button(root, text="Submit", command=lambda: show(var1.get(), var2.get(), var3.get(), var4.get(), )).pack()

x = Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The initial checked list of items will post, but, then, suppose one wants to clear the screen using the clear button.  That's when I run into the following error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-55-b81bc2ffe1d0>", line 22, in clear
    Label1.destroy()
NameError: name 'Label1' is not defined
```

My concern isnt so much in just fixing this one script, but I am interested in understanding what I did wrong and how to handle this type of error.

why is not the computer identifying 'Label1' as defined?

Comment: `Label1` is a [local variable](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python). You will also run into [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/7432) once you solve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `show()` function, at the very start of it, add `global Label1`.

Also, if you want: [What are Global and Local variables in Python?](https://www.stechies.com/global-local-variables-python/#:%7E:text=Difference%20between%20Local%20Variables%20and%20Global%20Variables%3A%20,a%20glo%20...%20%203%20more%20rows%20)